# iOS AVCapturePhotoOutput crashed due to shutter sounds

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avcapturephotooutput

My app had a crash sometimes when taking a photo:

```
[output capturePhotoWithSettings:avsettings delegate:self];
```

and the crash info:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] You are not authorized to use custom shutter sounds
```

crash device: iPhone7 plus

operation system: iOS 12.1.1，no jailbroken

So what is the cause of this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I had it recently in my app that allows to take pictures and record video on the same screen. The crash is thrown when a user rapidly hits "take a photo" and "take a video" buttons. Probably something asynchronous is going on in the background on the iOS side and you need to do some `deobunce`-ing.